# Can't play all songs on a playlist

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, playlist, scenebuilder

So I'm making an mp3 player with javafx that has a `ListView` where I drag and drop songs, I then select a song and press play to play it, you get the point..
Trouble is, with my current code, I can't play a sequence of more than two songs :/ (plays selected song, plays song next to it and then stops).
Here's the code:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        list.setItems(tracklist);
    }

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Duration pausetime = null;
    private int i;

    ObservableList<String> tracklist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ArrayList<File> playlist = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();

    @FXML
    private Slider slider;

    @FXML
    private Button open;

    @FXML
    private Label csong;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> list;

    public void getsongfromlist(){
        i = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    }

    public void slide(int a){
        slider.setMin(0.0);
        slider.setValue(0.0);

        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>(){

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observableValue, Duration duration,
                    Duration current) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                slider.setMax(players.get(a).getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
                slider.setValue(current.toSeconds());
            }
        });
    }

    public void move(){
        player.seek(Duration.seconds(slider.getValue()));
    }

    public void play(){              //This is where im getting it wrong
        if (player != null){
            player.stop();
        }
        this.player = players.get(i);
        player.play();
        slide(i);
        csong.setText(playlist.get(i).getName());
        for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++){
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
            i++;
            list.getSelectionModel().select(i);
            player = players.get(i);
            player.play();
            slide(i);
            csong.setText(playlist.get(i).getName());
            }
        });
    }
    }

    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasFiles()) {
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        } else {
            event.consume();
        }
    }

    public void dropped(DragEvent event){
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()){
            success = true;
            for (File file:db.getFiles()){
                tracklist.add(file.getName());
                playlist.add(file);
                try {
                    final Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
                    final MediaPlayer set = new MediaPlayer(media);
                    players.add(set);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but try replacing

```
for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++){
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run(){
        i++;
        list.getSelectionModel().select(i);
        player = players.get(i);
        player.play();
        slide(i);
        csong.setText(playlist.get(i).getName());
        }
    });
}
```

with

```
player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++ ;
        play();
    }
});
```

and move the line

```
list.getSelectionModel().select(i);
```

from the `endOfMedia` listener to the main body of the `play()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing `if player != null`.
Try a different value, such as the number of songs you want to play.

Comment: Thanks but that line is just for making sure the program doesn't play two songs at the same time, and it's working as intended. My problem is getting the for loop to iterate over the whole playlist instead of just two songs. Thanks anyway :)